# How to package Qt with an application (but not statically)

Tags: c++, qt

I am looking to create a Qt application that contains all the files it needs in it's app folder. Whilst I don't want to compile Qt statically, can some Qt files be distributed next to the application without having to install Qt on every client's PC?

If so:

- What Qt files should be packaged?
- Is this permitted by the Qt license? (not the commercial one from digia)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the documentation: [Deploying Qt Applications](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/deployment.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can find out very easily which Qt .dll files you have to provide in your package by using DependenyWalker. More info here: http://www.dependencywalker.com/

It scans a executable for dependencies to libraries.